# What's the DRAT word of my SSD?

Tags: forensics, data-recovery, ssd

[This article](https://www.forensicfocus.com/articles/recovering-evidence-from-ssd-drives-in-2014-understanding-trim-garbage-collection-and-exclusions/) on forensicfocus.com says the following about Deterministic Read After TRIM (emphasis mine):

> As a result, the data returned by SSD drives supporting DRAT as opposed to DZAT can be all zeroes or other words of data, or it could be the **original pre-trim data** stored in that logical page.

The sentence makes it sound like trimmed data could be recovered on some SSDs by simply asking the SSD controller for it.

`hdparm` tells me that my SSD ([SanDisk SSD PLUS](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12504/%7E/sandisk-ultra-plus-ssd-specifications) 1000GB) has DRAT enabled:

```
Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
Deterministic read data after TRIM
```

I'd like to find out which word the SSD deterministically returns for trimmed data.

Comment: what do you mean by this "which word the SSD deterministically returns for trimmed data"?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex: The SSD has a certain byte sequence (word) that it reports as the contents of a page after that page was deleted. It could be all zeros, a different byte sequence that's hardcoded into the SSD's controller, or, according to the article, the contents of the page before it was "deleted". I'd like to know a way to find out which of those possibilities it is.

Comment: I'm sorry that I never got back this question.  I was busy writing code for StackOverflow questions. Concerning your question, I know that every disk reports differently.  I was looking for more tech data for your SanDisk, which allegedly does Trimming correctly.  Let me do some more research to see what I can find for your disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The DRAT word seems to be zeros

I used the following experiment to conclude that the DRAT word of the SSD in question is zeros:

1. Create a small file and get the block number of its file contents.
2. Delete the file.
3. Run [`fstrim`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html) to send the TRIM command to the SSD's controller. My OS (Arch Linux 5.12.9) doesn't trim SSDs automatically, discussion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649964/is-mounting-with-discard-needed-for-trim).
4. Read the contents of the deleted file's block with [`debugfs`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html): It's all zeros.

Here's a script performing those steps:

```
#!/bin/sh

file="test_file"
echo "Current date: $(date)" > "$file"; sync
# Get the device of our test file, for example "/dev/sda1"
device=$(df -P "$file" | awk 'END{print $1}')
file_abs_path="$(realpath "$file")"
# The block of the file's contents
block=$(sudo debugfs -R "blocks \"$file_abs_path\"" "$device")
echo "Block used by "$file": $block"
# fstrim needs the mountpoint of the file system, e.g. "/"
mountpoint=$(stat -c %m "$file")
rm "$file"; sync
# Send TRIM to make the SSD delete unused blocks. Might take a while
sudo fstrim "$mountpoint"
# Read the contents of the deleted file, -D bypasses the buffer cache
sudo debugfs -D -R "block_dump $block" "$device"
```

As a side note, if you remove the call to `fstrim` in this script, as shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649964/is-mounting-with-discard-needed-for-trim), you can see that the contents of the deleted file can be recovered.